# Pandas: inserting rows of even number years

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I have the following abridged [dataframe](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/yearsofserv):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'end': [2007, 2013, 2014, 2013, 2014], 'id.thomas'\
: ['136', '136', '136', '172', '172'], 'years_exp': ['14', '20', '21', \
'14', '15']}, index=[2,3,4,5,6])

    end     id.thomas   years_exp
2   2007    136         14
3   2013    136         20
4   2014    136         21
5   2013    172         14
6   2014    172         15
```

where `end` is representative of years. I would like to expand the `end`and `years_exp`column to account account for the missing years:

```
    end     id.thomas   years_exp
2   2007    136         14
3   2008    136         15
4   2009    136         16
5   2010    136         17
6   2011    136         18
7   2012    136         19
8   2013    136         20
9   2014    136         21
10  2013    172         14
11  2014    172         15
```

I have been working on this for about 20 hours, trying to 'engineer' a fix. Does anyone know of a simple Python/Pandas tool/method for accomplishing this task?

Comment: Do you care about the index order? Are the 'id.thomas' and 'years_exp' columns calculated, or is it okay for them to be empty?

Comment: @Nathan Clement: Thanks for your response. I don't care about the index order. It is important that the `id.thomas` is maintained. `years_exp` is my main take-away from the operation. It will be merged later to another database. `years_exp`has already been calculated from another [dataframe](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/yearsofserv)

Comment: So basically what you want is to have a new range of "End" rows that starts with the first year and ends with the last year, but doesn't skip any years?

Comment: and repeats for every id in `id.thomas`. Yes Sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes the first `end` and `years_exp` fields for a given `id.thomas`, and then enumerates these forward to the final year.

```
final_year = 2014
>>> pd.DataFrame([(year, id_, n) 
                  for id_, end, years_exp in df1.groupby('id.thomas').first().itertuples() 
                  for n, year in enumerate(range(end, final_year + 1), years_exp)], 
                 columns=['end', 'id.thomas', 'years_exp'])
    end  id.thomas  years_exp
0  2007        136         14
1  2008        136         15
2  2009        136         16
3  2010        136         17
4  2011        136         18
5  2012        136         19
6  2013        136         20
7  2014        136         21
8  2013        172         14
9  2014        172         15
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander! I'm about to literally pass-out. Please do not mind that I will implement this after a short nap and confirm the results by acknowledging your working solution. Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: Guilty as charged. I applied your code but am getting a `name 'final_year' is not defined`  error. Also, this endeavor has become a little more complicated than I originally thought. I'm thinking to open another question.

Comment: My bad; Thank you for bringing that to my attention. Love your sense of humor! Yes, still a little sleepy. This issue is kicking my but

Answer (score 1):

If `years_exp` doesn't yet matter, you can just build the dataframe from groupby :

```
df2 =pd.concat(
   [pd.DataFrame({'id.thomas':id,'end':range(s.min(),s.max()+1)})
                     for (id,s) in df1.groupby('id.thomas').end])
```

For

```
    end id.thomas
0  2007       136
1  2008       136
2  2009       136
3  2010       136
4  2011       136
5  2012       136
6  2013       136
7  2014       136
0  2013       172
1  2014       172
```